# SQL Join data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:
`skill_categories(id, name)` -- list of categories
`skills(id, skill_category_id, name)` -- Sub-categories for each skill category
`contributors(id, name, skill_id_1, skill_id_2, skill_id_3)` -- A person can have up to 3 skills

I want to query the `skill_category_id, skill_category_name, skill_id and skill_name` for each `skill_id` field in a contributor.

From what I have read, I think SQL JOINs can be used to achieve this and have written such a query.

```
SELECT s.skill_category_id AS skill_category_id, 
       sc.name AS skill_category_name,
       s.id AS skill_id, 
       s.name AS name
FROM skills AS s
INNER JOIN skill_categories AS sc 
      ON s.skill_category_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN contributors AS c
      ON c.skill_id_1 = s.id
      OR c.skill_id_2 = s.id
      OR c.skill_id_3 = s.id
WHERE c.id = $id
ORDER BY s.name, sc.name ASC
```

Is this the best way to perform such a query?

Comment: use inner select it will be faster

Comment: The previous and succeeding assertion are both misinformed. This appears to be valid solution. Define best.

Comment: Do SQL subqueries Turion. Much easier and faster than OR on JOINS

Comment: You can simplify it to `ON s.id IN (c.skill_id_1, c.skill_id_2, c.skill_id_3)`

Comment: The best solution would be to normalize your design. Instead of multiple `skill_id_X` column, have a many-to-many table that relates contributor IDs to skills. Then you won't have an arbitrary limit of 3 skills.

Comment: Use `explain` before your query, but it looks absolutely fine.

Comment: @Strawberry By best, I mean query efficiency.

Comment: @Barmar My case is specific to at least 1 skill and at most 3 skills. Although I think I read somewhere that many-to-many relationships are bad, can you give an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Barmar has spotted what I missed. Normalisation is key. I'm fairly confident that a normalised design, and appropriate indexes will trounce Gordon's concerns in respect of IN/OR. But I'd be delighted to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the best way -- especially from a performance perspective.  `OR` (or `IN`) are performance killers for joins.

It is better to add more joins, one for each skill category.  So, this should have better performance:

```
SELECT s.skill_category_id AS skill_category_id,  sc.name AS skill_category_name,
       s.id AS skill_id,  s.name AS name
FROM skills s INNER JOIN
     skill_categories sc 
     ON s.skill_category_id = sc.id LEFT JOIN
     contributors c1
     ON c.skill_id_1 = s.id LEFT JOIN
     contributors c2
     ON c1.skill_id_2 = s.id LEFT JOIN
     contributors c3
     ON c3.skill_id_3 = s.id
WHERE $id in (c1.id, c2.id, c3.id)
ORDER BY s.name, sc.name ASC
```

The query would be simpler if you had separate rows for each skill, rather than separate columns.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using LEFT JOINs for the skill_id?

Comment: @turion . . . Because they might not all exist.  You don't want to filter out a row where `$id` matches the first skill, but the other two are `NULL`.